# Kitten urine cleaning

Tags: taharah, najis

I am aware kitten urine is najis but to clean it is what confused me, I used some anti bacterial wet wipes and wiped the area and the scent of the smell was gone. Is it clean?

Comment: What type of surface is it? In general you should pour water on it.

Comment: It was carpet, I just got some wipes and kept wiping them with 2/3 each time until the smell was gone

Comment: Wet wipes will not purify it. Rather you need to wash it with excess water. I think there are several article on the web which describe the method of purifying a carpet.